# Filtering comments with Redux Reselect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

I'm trying to filter and display comments whose 'postID' matches with current post id. I'm using `Redux/Reselect`, it works but sometimes it returns an error that says `post._id` is undefined/null..

Here is the code:

```
const getAllComments = state => state.comments.comments;
const getPost = state => state.posts.post;

export const getCommentsByPostID = createSelector([ getAllComments, getPost ], (comments, post) => {
  return comments.filter((c) => c.postID == post._id);
})
```

I'm calling `getComments()` action in `componentDidMount` after `getPost(params.id)`.
How to be sure that post is defined ? Should I call the in render method ?

Comment: Is getPost asynchronous? You might want to wait until it's actually been retrieved if so.

Comment: I tried like `post && comments ? comments.map... : <Loader />`

Comment: I checked for post in render method and dispatched the action, seems to work..

Comment: @merko can you please check my answer? I pointed out what's the problem and I provided you a possible and very detailed solution. Please appreciate the SO contributors effort and time and show respect to all of us - as commenting / voting / accepting the answer, instead of showing us disengagement!

Answer (score 1):

So before calling the selectors, you have to make sure your data (`posts` and `comments`) is already fetched and available for you.

You can try the following flow and later (if it works for you), you can improve it:

1. For each one Entity (`Post`, `Comment`, and etc), you will keep a new meta property called`fetching`. With this property, you will always know the current state of your data. Also it will prevent you from multiple API calls to the same resources (imagine you have two components, these need and fetch the posts, so only 1 API request should be invoked). It will have three possible values:

   1. `not-started` - the data is not started, no data fetching request is triggered.
   2. `fetching` - the data is in progress of being fetched.
   3. `fetched`- the data is already fetched.
2. In `componentDidMount` you will invoke your API calls (action creators), which respectively will change the `fetching` state.
3. The last step is in `mapStateToProps` where you will invoke your selectors, only if the data is fetched, something like that:

```
const isFetching = entity => ['not-started', 'fetching'].includes(entity.fetching)

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  // Here you wait your data to be fetched,
  // and return `isFetching` flag, in order to show a <Loader /> component,
  // or something else
  if (isFetching(state.posts) || isFetching(state.comments)) return { isFetching: true }

  // Here the data is already fetched, and you can call your selectors.
  return {
   comments: state.comments,
   posts: state.posts
  }
}
```

That's the flow I'm using in my projects. As I already said, you can start implementing it in a very basic way and later (if fits you) you can create some abstractions, these will reduce the boilerplate code. For example - you can create a HOC, where you will pass the needed Entities only, and the HOC will render your component, once the Entities are fetched. Something like that: `DataProviderHOC(PostsList, ['Post', 'Comment'])`. `PostsList` component will be rendered, only if `Post, Comment` Entities are fetched. As simple and clean as possible.